# requireJs / TypeScript, combine multiple classes into a single module?

Tags: typescript, requirejs

How can I combine multiple files into a single module ?
Say I have a folder with multiple typescript classes e.g.

```
app
  module1
    foo1.ts
    foo2.ts
    ....
    module1.ts
```

In any classes which uses any of the module1 defined classes, I would like to be able to include the dependencies using a single import like

```
import {Foo1, Foo2} from "./module1/module1"
```

rather than importing individual classes like

```
 import {Foo1} from "./module1/foo1"
 import {Foo2} from "./module1/foo2"
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but it seems to work for what I need 
in module1.ts simply define export for the classes

```
export * from "./foo1";
export * from "./foo2";
```